# How do you mimic multi row horizontal scroll table behavior with CSS and Divs?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do you mimic table behavior with CSS and Divs?
Is it possible to mimic the table behavior below:

1. Two rows with horizontal overflow and one horizontal overflow scrollbar
2. No spacing between cells

To see an example, http://jsfiddle.net/srakestraw/BcQbk/3/.   Here is the table code:

```
<div style="width:500px; overflow:auto;">
    <table width="1000px" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 - Cell 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Cell 2</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Cell 3</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Cell 4</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Cell 5</td>
            <td>Row 1 - Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 - Cell 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Cell 2</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Cell 3</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Cell 4</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Cell 5</td>
            <td>Row 2 - Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Style Sheet:

```
 <style>
        td
        {
            width: 200px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
```

I am close with the following code but cannot eliminate the spacing between cells or control the horizontal scroll for multiple rows.

```
<style>
       .slideContainer{
             white-space: nowrap;
             overflow:auto;
          }
        .slide{ 
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            white-space: normal;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            vertical-align:top;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
      </style>

<div style="width:500px;">
    <div class="slideContainer">
        <div class="slide">Cell 1</div>
        <div class="slide">Cell 2</div>
        <div class="slide">Cell 3</div>
        <div class="slide">Cell 4</div>
        <div class="slide">Cell 5</div>
        <div class="slide">Cell 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The end product will be more complicated with merged cells and I am leaning toward just using a table.  My preference is to use divs to make it easier to implement front-end layout manipulation.

It is not a true data table but is similar. I posted a mock-up at http://www.volunteeryourself.com/sch.htm.

Comment: Are you importing tabular data? Tables aren't the devil but if used for layout-only purposes they are... You are obliged to used tables for tabular type data

Comment: May I ask what content will be going in here? Tables are bad for layout, but if you are trying to represent data then a table may actually be the correct element (both semantically, and stylistically) to use.

Comment: It is not a data table but is data table like.  I posted my an example at http://www.volunteeryourself.com/sch.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `margin-right:-5px;` to `.slide` class:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/BcQbk/4/

Aside from that if it is tabular data by all means use tables, that is what they are for,

They become evil when you use them for page LAYOUT.

Comment: I agree on tables for layout.  This is a mix of data and layout.  I posted a mock up at http://www.volunteeryourself.com/sch.htm.  I am trying to determine the best approach.

Comment: @scottrakes I think for what you are trying to achieve divs+css would be the best-least complicated method, and thus the above method suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I mocked it up and have working as desired.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace between your `div`s is screwing you up.

```
<div style="width:500px;">
    <div class="slideContainer">
        <div class="slide">Cell 1</div><!--
     --><div class="slide">Cell 2</div><!--
     --><div class="slide">Cell 3</div><!--
     --><div class="slide">Cell 4</div><!--
     --><div class="slide">Cell 5</div><!--
     --><div class="slide">Cell 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

jswolf speaks true. inline-block makes your DIVs behave like words flowing in lines of text, so any whitespace between them gives a space. Image this instead:

```
<div>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>am</span>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>robot</span>
</div>
```

That renders out as "I am a robot" not "Iamarobot."

You can use comments as mentioned, or run everything together on one line.